# Vim key mapping how to map <leader> + key press together?

Tags: vim

Currently I have this mapping:

```
noremap <leader>[ gT
```

Everytime I need to press `leader`, keyup, then <kbd>[</kbd> to go to previous tab, is it possible to map it similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> ones like <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> so I don't have to keyup `<leader>` for keep going previous tabs?

I tried `<leader-[>` and it didn't work

Comment: Normally, no. However it looks like somebody wrote a script to allow mappings for simultaneous keypresses: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425. Will try out and report back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vanilla vim doesn't support mappings for simultaneous input. But, I found this script on the vim website.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425

It's called Arpeggio. Usage is exactly as you'd expect, so for your case:

```
:Arpeggio noremap <Leader>[ gT
```

It looks like there's some caveats w/r/t multiple mappings with the same keys; not familiar enough with the script to say much though. Reading through their documentation would be a good place to start.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmmmm, I was hoping it was possible to do it with vanilla vim.